# filtering a mapped object based on React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm trying to filter my map array by the `:reviewId` in my router(v4) url

the code works if I set it manually to the routeId parameter {review.items.filter(item => item.id === 2)`

and `{this.props.match.params.reviewId}` also displays the routeId parameter but putting them together doesn't display any results and no console errors.

Route

```
<Route exact path="/reviews/:reviewId" component={Review} />
```

**json data**

```
const reviews = [
{
id: '1',
cat: 'film',
items: [
  { id: 1, name: 'Review 1', text: 'bla bla review 1', img: 'http://epn.tv/wp-content/themes/elecplay-2014/images/hexrotr/hexrotr_reviews_two_on.png' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Review 2', text: 'bla bla review 2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Review 3', text: 'bla bla review 3' },
],
},
{
id: '2',
cat: 'music',
items: [
  { id: 1, name: 'Review 1', text: 'bla bla review 1', img: 'http://epn.tv/wp-content/themes/elecplay-2014/images/hexrotr/hexrotr_reviews_two_on.png' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Review 2', text: 'bla bla review 2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Review 3', text: 'bla bla review 3' },
],
},
]
export default reviews
```

**review.jsx**

```
import reviews from '../Reviews/const'

export default class Reviews extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-
line react/prefer-stateless-function

  static propTypes = {
    match: React.PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  }

  render() {
    const revs = reviews.map(review =>
      <div>
    <div key={review.id} />
    {review.items.filter(item => item.id === this.props.match.params.reviewId)
    .map(item =>
      <div className="cell">
        <div key={item.id}>
          <img src={item.img} alt={item.name} />
          <div>{item.text}</div>
        </div>
      </div>,
    )}
  </div>,
)

return (
  <div>
    {this.props.match.params.reviewId}
    { revs }
  </div>
)
 }
}
```

Comment: // eslint-disable-
line react/prefer-stateless-function

That should all be on one line - it may be causing an error in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this is a type mismatch issue, `this.props.match.params.reviewId` will return a `string` value, and id is an `integer` value.

So instead of `===` use `==`.

Like this:

```
item.id == this.props.match.params.reviewId
```

**Reason:** `===` checks the value and type both.

To verify this use:

`console.log(typeOf(this.props.match.params.reviewId), typeOf(item.id))`

inside `filter` and check the result.

Try this:

```
render() {
    const revs = reviews.map(review =>
      <div>
        <div key={review.id} />
        {
          review.items.filter(item => {
              console.log(typeOf(this.props.match.params.reviewId), typeOf(item.id)) 
              return item.id == this.props.match.params.reviewId; 
          })
          .map(item =>
            <div className="cell">
              <div key={item.id}>
                <img src={item.img} alt={item.name} />
                <div>{item.text}</div>
            </div>
            </div>
        )}
      </div>
)
```

Comment: Either that - or make sure they are of the same type - one may be an integer while the other a string.

Comment: So i was passing the id in as an integer and react router was expecting a string, I've now added a 'slug' to my json data `{ id: 2, slug 'review-2' name: 'Review 2', text: 'bla bla review 2' },` and  changed `{review.items.filter(item => item.slug === this.props.match.params.reviewId)` now works!